# error:can not find Symbol method execAction(String)

Tags: java, android, database

I tried to use open source project for school app. However, I coded my own database and deleted privious one. When I try to run my app, log cat displays following error: error:can not find Symbol method execAction(String). There several execAction function in the project and each of them has redline underlined.Please somebody see my code and tell me what the issue is.
Appbase.execAction
   Here is what I tried:

AppBase.class

```
package com.andisofttechnology.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AppBase extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> basicFields;
    gridAdapter adapter;
    public static ArrayList<String> divisions ;
    GridView gridView;
    public static DatabaseHandler handler;
    public static Activity activity;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mai_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);
        basicFields = new ArrayList<>();
        handler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        activity = this;

        getSupportActionBar().show();
        divisions = new ArrayList();
        divisions.add("S1 COMPUTER SCIENCE");
        divisions.add("S2 COMPUTER SCIENCE");
        divisions.add("S3 COMPUTER SCIENCE");
        divisions.add("S4 COMPUTER SCIENCE");
        divisions.add("S5 COMPUTER SCIENCE");
        divisions.add("S6 COMPUTER SCIENCE");
        divisions.add("S7 COMPUTER SCIENCE");
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
        basicFields.add("ATTENDANCE");
        basicFields.add("SCHEDULER");
        basicFields.add("NOTES");
        basicFields.add("PROFILE");
        basicFields.add("CGPA CALCULATOR");
        adapter = new gridAdapter(this,basicFields);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void loadSettings(MenuItem item) {
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }

    public void loadAbout(MenuItem item) {
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this,About.class);
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}
```

Scheduler.class

```
package com.andisofttechnology.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class scheduler extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener{

    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> subs;
    ArrayList<String> subx;
    ArrayList<String> times;
    Activity activity = this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scheduler);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_sch);
        assert fab != null;
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent launchIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), make_schedule.class);
                startActivity(launchIntent);
            }
        });

        subs = new ArrayList<>();
        times = new ArrayList<>();
        subx = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.schedulerList);
        loadSchedules();
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    }

    private void loadSchedules() {
        subs.clear();
        times.clear();
        String qu = "SELECT * FROM SCHEDULE ORDER BY subject";
        Cursor cursor = AppBase.handler.execQuery(qu);
        if(cursor==null||cursor.getCount()==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No Schedules Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                subx.add(cursor.getString(1));
                subs.add(cursor.getString(1) + "\nfor " + cursor.getString(0) + "\nat " + cursor.getString(2) + " : " + cursor.getString(3));
                times.add(cursor.getString(2));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,subs);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alert.setTitle("Delete Schedule?");
        alert.setMessage("Do you want to delete this schedule ?");

        alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String qu = "DELETE FROM SCHEDULE WHERE subject = '" + subx.get(position) + "' AND timex = '" + times.get(position) + "'";
                if (AppBase.handler.execAction(qu)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loadSchedules();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loadSchedules();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }

    public void refresh(MenuItem item) {
        loadSchedules();
    }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.scheduler_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `DatabaseHandler` class have an `execAction(String)` method ?

Comment: The error should show a stacktrace. That will tell you where exactly the error occured